# Object push Firebase, how to remove key names from pushed items

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have this `Object.key` code that pushes all items:

```
const cloned_items = [];

Object.keys(items).sort().map(key => {
    let item = {
        [`item-${uid}`]: {
            item: false
        }
    }

    cloned_items.push({ ...item });
});

database.ref('/app/items').update({
    ...cloned_items
})
```

but this produces following result:

```
"0" : {
    "timeslot-87dah2j" : {
        item: false
    }
},
"1" : {
    "timeslot-7s1ahju" : {
        item: false
    }
}
```

instead of:

```
"timeslot-87dah2j" : {
    item: false
},
"timeslot-7s1ahju" : {
    item: false
}
```

any idea ?

Comment: Nor your output and desired output are in valid JavaScript notation. You should add the surrounding `{ }` or `[ ]`. And is it `key` or `uid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to create a plain object, not an array.

In that case:

```
const cloned_items = Object.assign(...Object.keys(items).map(uid =>
    ({ [`item-${uid}`]: {item: false} })
));
```

NB: sorting is of no use when creating an object -- its keys are supposed to have no specific order.

Comment: No luck, @NinaScholz, I could not find anything like that in the last month.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an array of objects. Seems like you want to use `.reduce()` to create a single object from the array.

```
const cloned_items = Object.keys(items).sort().reduce((obj, key) =>
    Object.assign(obj, { [`item-${uid}`]: { item: false } })
, {});
```

Your code doesn't show where `uid` is coming from, but I assume you meant `key` there, along with `timeslot` instead of `item`.

---

You may find `Object.defineProperty` to be cleaner, though you'll need to set up the property descriptor as you want it.

```
const cloned_items = Object.keys(items).sort().reduce((obj, key) => 
    Object.defineProperty(obj, `item-${uid}`, {value:{item: false}})
, {});
```